# Citroen C2 VTS 1.6L 2007 - Not starting - sometimes clicking and other times nothing at all

Tags: starting, citroen

I have a Citroen C2 VTS 1.6L 2007, with a very similar problem to;
[Unable to start the vehicle depending on how long it has previously been driven](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6538/unable-to-start-the-vehicle-depending-on-how-long-it-has-previously-been-driven/9755#9755)
I am currently trying to fault find.

Symptoms: The car will not start when the key is turned on in the ignition. Somethings I can here small relays and the solenoid picking up and other times nothing happens. Sometimes only the small relays pick up. I clutch started the car and after driving around for 10 minutes the car came up if a fault on the inside display, 'electric circuit fault'. What I have read on the internet is this fault is a separate fault to do with my alternator?

I have pulled out the starter motor and tested it on a 12V supply. It worked fine. With the starter motor disconnected, I tested for 12V at the starter motor connection terminal with someone else turning the ignition on. I should have had 12V, but did not get anything. I tested the battery and it was fine.

Can someone please help me with this?

Also the solenoid is not located directly on top of the starter motor like most other cars. Does anyone know where it is located on my car?

Comment: It sounds like you have a grounding (earth) problem at your battery, like it isn't making a full connection all of the time. Assuming this is a side post battery, it's easy for these to get corroded and not make contact, or for them to just not make good contact at all. If you were jumping directly between terminals, you wouldn't notice any problem with the battery. First place I'd start, anyway.

Comment: I ended up taking it to an auto electrician.
Apparently the motor I had removed was the fuel pump and not the starter motor.
The auto electrician removed the starter motor and found that there was large big up of carbon in around the comm of the motor. Replaced its brushes and cleaned it out. 
The starter motor was re-installed and the car now starts fine. All alarms/faults have cleared.

Summary: Starter motor needed to be re-conditioned.

Comment: @Luke : You can post it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The OP resolved this issue as per his [comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9764/citroen-c2-vts-1-6l-2007-not-starting-sometimes-clicking-and-other-times-not#comment12052_9764):

> I ended up taking it to an auto electrician.
>
> Apparently the motor I had removed was the fuel pump and not the starter motor.
>
> The auto electrician removed the starter motor and found that there was large big up of carbon in around the comm of the motor. Replaced its brushes and cleaned it out. The starter motor was re-installed and the car now starts fine. All alarms/faults have cleared.
>
> Summary: Starter motor needed to be re-conditioned.

Comment: BAM.     Answererd.........